# Javascripts methods in arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I'm learning about arrays in Code.org.

So there are methods like `insertItem(list, index, item)` in code.org, but as I read many books about arrays in javaScript, none of them talked about the `insertItem` Method.

I wanted to know if `insertItem` is generic to JS or is it just specifically made for the code.org platform?

Comment: sounds like a function

Answer (score 2):

That method is only on code.org
https://docs.code.org/applab/insertItem/

But JS has a similar method you can use:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2):

`insertItem()` is purely code.org

https://docs.code.org/applab/insertItem/

To do this in regular javascript, you would:

1. If you wanted to insert the item into the end of the array, you would use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2];

console.log(array);
array.push("item");
console.log(array);
```

2. If you wanted to replace an item in the array (in which you know the index), you would use `array[index] = item;`

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2];

console.log(array);
array[1] = "item";
console.log(array);
```

3. If you wanted to replace an item in an array by knowing the value, but not the index, you would use `array[array.indexOf(value)] = item;`

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2];

console.log(array);
array[array.indexOf(1)] = "item";
console.log(array);
```

4. Finally, if you wanted to insert an item into the array, you would use [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). To insert an item after index 2, you would use `array.splice(2, 0, item)`.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2];

console.log(array);
array.splice(1, 0, "item");
console.log(array);
```

Code.org probably uses the following function to make life easier for you:

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2];

function insertItem(list, index, item) {
  list.splice(index, 0, item);
  return list;
}

console.log(array);
array = insertItem(array, 1, "item");
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method by name `insertItem` for Array in javascript. Also it seems `insertItem(list, index, item)` is a `function` and it accepts three arguments.

You can get list of javascript array methods in this [**link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1):

There's no JavaScript function named `insertItem` - however, there's an almost identical method named [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - syntax like `list.splice(index, 0, item)`:

```js
var list = [1, 2, 4];
var item = 3;
var index = 2;
list.splice(index, 0, item);
console.log(list);
```